# Prepare syntax tree (ast) to easily perform short circuit operations

Tags: c#, syntax, compiler-construction, abstract-syntax-tree, short-circuiting

What is the best way to prepare a syntax tree containing conditions to allow easy and fast `short curcuit` usage?

The rules of `short circuit` in general are very easy:

1. If one component in an `and` block returns false, the complete block will return false and execution can be exited
2. If one component in an `or` block returns true, the complete block will return true and execution can be exited

So for example this simple statement will be evaluated to the following syntax tree `1 = 0 and 1 = 1`:

```
       and
    /      \
   =        =
 /  \      /  \
1    0    1    1
```

In this case it is easy. After executing the first part of the tree (branch),
the execution will be exited it only can return false. But if the tree gets more
complex, there must be a way to be more efficient. Or is this already the most
efficient way?

For example, how does the `c#` compiler evaluate the syntax tree in this cases?

**EDIT**

Should I write all conditions in a simple list, and branch to the end if `true` or `false` is not possible? So that i have no `and` and `or` parts at the end?

Thank you all a lot!

Comment: If i'm not mistaken, the compiler will try to read your statement from left to right. For each component, it will evaluate to `True` or `False`. Then will check which operation it should be doing next (AND/OR). Depending on the result of the previous value, it will or not choose to evaluate the right part of the condition. The result of these two parts and the logical operator will be used as the left part for the next one. (That's how I learned it, so that would be the 'simplest' way). The C# compiler might work differently

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But wouldn't it be better to "remove" the tree and make a flat list of it with some labels, branching or a kind of *goto* so that it only has to execute some sequence of conditions an jump over not neeed conditions? So the executing part does not need any *short-curcuit*-logic. For example like this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_CIL_instructions (the branching commands)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your definition of short circuiting doesn't quite match that of C# and other languages. In most (presumably all) languages that have short circuiting the behavior depends on the value of the left operand only, that is:

- `left && right` always evaluates `left` and only evaluates `right` if `left` was true.
- `left || right` always evaluates `left` and only evaluates `right` if `left` was false.

So the rules of the language guarantee you that the right operand will never be tried first, even if the compiler may think that trying the right operand first would be more efficient. This way you know that `list == null || list.IsEmpty()` can't ever throw a null pointer exception.

So to answer your question, the compiler won't generate anything more efficient than "evaluate the left operand and then evaluate the right operand only if you have to" because anything else would break the rules of the language.

PS: In theory it would be possible for the compiler to reorder the operands if it can prove that they don't have any side-effects, but to the best of my knowledge that is not done. Either way that would not happen at the AST level.

PPS: The C# compiler does not evaluate the AST, it generates code from it. It's a compiler, not an interpreter.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What do you think about the *branching* point  in the comments of my question? Thank you a lot :) Good point that I wrote down the wrong rules.

Comment: @BendEg As I said, compilers don't evaluate the AST, nor do most interpreters. Instead they generate code from it, which will indeed contain branching instructions. That is, the code generated for `a && b && c` will indeed jump over the instructions generated for `b` and `c` if `a` is false. But that is only more efficient than evaluating the AST directly, in the way that evaluating bytecode (or machine code) is always more efficient than evaluating the AST. That is, if you do evaluate the AST directly, you still only evaluate `b && c` if `a` is true (and `c` only if `b` is true as well).

Comment: Ok, i get what you mean. Thank you for your time!